# Windows SSH Tunnel Manager

Tags: windows, ssh, vpn

What application do you use on windows to create SSH tunnels

On Linux I use [gSTM](http://sourceforge.net/projects/gstm/), and on OSX I have used [STM](http://projects.tynsoe.org/en/stm/), but I am not able to find any similar free tools on windows.

I don't want to use putty, or plink for these tunnels, because, I am looking for something that will sit in the tray starting stopping tunnels can easily be done by right-clicking.  Ideally the configuration will be stored in a text file or something so I can automate the  install of the app, keys, and tunnel configuration on a computer using a script.

Free is proffered, but please post information about any good windows SSH tunnel manager.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For what you're looking for, I believe you'll be happy with either the **'Putty-tunnel-manager'** (**'PTM'**?) project or **'Putty Tray'** solutions.  The two get their sessions from Putty, though you can move/copy the sessions to PTM as oppose to putty tray which uses putty all the way.  Only PTM will allow you to stop and start a tunnel session from the taskbar... Putty tray will allow you to start it only.  I've used Tunnelier, but it doesn't seem to be what you're looking for since I couldn't find an easy way of creating taskbar items(sessions).

I like Putty Tray better because I like having access to a terminal window/session when I load a tunnel (makes me feel more powerful by having access to Putty's configuration as oppose to the limited settings offered in PTM)... but maybe you want this as a solution for end-users, so with PTM you only create your tunnel (no terminal window opens).  The nice thing about this is that if you left-click on the icon it shows you your opened sessions.  A minus for PTM, it gave me a UI programming error when trying to call the taskbar when the settings page was in the background... looks like a bug.

All in all, that's my assessment for the already posted solutions.

---

I'd like to add another solution I found though it might be a little more bloated than putty and the above solutions.  In any case, I thought it was a worthy mention since it's free and pretty full-featured:

## **XShell**


Free for home and education

[alt text http://www.netsarang.com/e_image/xsh_161.gif](http://www.netsarang.com/e_image/xsh_161.gif)

This [**features**](http://www.netsarang.com/products/xsh_key_features.html) page is pretty informative, so I won't rewrite it here.  I found this client to be pretty full-feature which was something I was looking for, specially for the Tabs and easy launching of sessions/tunnels through the taskbar.  Here's a couple of highlighted features listed on the site:

- Using full screen view to use your entire monitor as a terminal
- Using Compose bar to send a string to multiple servers at once.
- Using tunneling bar for real time channel monitoring (SSH)
- Using Dynamic Port Forwarding with Tunneling bar (SSH)
- Using local shell interface to control Xshell

The application sessions are text-based and saved to the user's profile which could be easily scripted '\Application Data\NetSarang\Xshell\Sessions\Links'

The application comes with **Xactivator.exe (276KB)** which is the taskbar app that can be launched at startup, finds the sessions and allows you quick launch for them... unfortunately, it does not provide a disconnect in the taskbar.

> Compatible with:
>
> - Microsoft Windows 98/ME/NT/2000/XP/2003/Vista
> - Microsoft Windows Terminal Server
> - Citrix MetaFrame for Windows

Answer (score 14):

Use [PuTTY Tray](http://haanstra.eu/putty/). It is based on PuTTY and works from the tray. Also, the current version of [pageant](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html) (the [ssh-agent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ssh-agent) from [PuTTY](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/)) supports opening PuTTY sessions from the context menu.

Comment: +1 for PuTTY tray. Did not hear of this improved PuTTY before now. Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

I have used [Tunnelier](http://www.bitvise.com/tunnelier) in the past.  While it's only free for non-commercial use, it works really well.

Comment: From the page you linked: "Since version 3.60, Tunnelier is free for individual use, as well as for limited use inside organizations."

Comment: I believe the client is freeware while the server component (WinSSH) is shareware.

Comment: The server component, WinSSHD, is also free for personal use. From the Bitvise website: "When the personal edition is chosen during installation, WinSSHD can be used free of charge by non-commercial personal users."

Comment: I agree. Bitvise Tunnelier and WinSSHD are by far the best products for SSH management for Windows that I have used.

Answer (score 2):

At Windows I use [MyEnTunnel](http://nemesis2.qx.net/pages/MyEnTunnel) which is a simple system tray application.

Answer (score 2):

While searching around for additional options I came across the putty-tunnel-manager [project](http://code.google.com/p/putty-tunnel-manager/) which looks like another pretty good option.