# Putty alternative for windows with support to remote port forwarding

Tags: windows, port, remote, putty

I have been trying to find an alternative to putty for windows. It needs to be portable and it must support remote port forwarding. Putty has had problems with its own implementation of remote port forwarding

http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/wishlist/portfwd-corrupt.html .

Although they state on the page that the problem might have been fixed, it clearly wasnt (and has been an open bug since 2003), thus, I need an alternative for it.

Ideas?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Windows SSH Tunnel Manager](http://serverfault.com/questions/3027/windows-ssh-tunnel-manager)

Answer (score 3):

I recommend you to use [**KiTTY**](http://kitty.9bis.com/), a fork from version 0.61 of PuTTY

[image]